# Roundabout jQuery plugin keypress arrow keys move left right

Tags: jquery-plugins, keypress

I'm using the Roundabout plugin ( http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout ) but can't work out how to use the preset callable methods, like animate to next / previous on keypress with the left/right arrow keys.

I can get keypress to work in general without using these presets but I really want to use the preset classes on various keypress's.  Any ideas?

The HTML

```
    <div id="carousel-container">
    <ul class="roundabout-holder">
       <li class="roundabout-moveable-item roundabout-in-focus"></li>
       <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
       <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
       <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
       <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery set up

```
    <script> // Calling the Roundabout plugin
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('ul').roundabout();
       });
    </script>

    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
      var direction = null;
      // handle cursor keys
      if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        // go left
        $('#roundabout-container').roundabout("animateToNextChild");
      } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        // go right
        $('#roundabout-container').roundabout("animateToPreviousChild");
      }
     if (direction != null) {
        $('ul.roundabout-holder li.roundabout-moveable-item').parent()[direction]().find('a').click();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

**The HTML**

```
   <ul class="pasador">
      <li><img src="fichas/01.jpg" alt="Award" /></li>
      <li><img src="fichas/02.jpg" alt="Backpack" /></li>
      etc ...
   </ul>
```

**JQUERY SET UP**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul.pasador').roundabout();
    });
</script>

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        $('ul.pasador').roundabout("animateToPreviousChild");
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        $('ul.pasador').roundabout("animateToNextChild");
    }
});
```